# Custom container control

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to create a CollapsiblePanel control, which is essentially just a panel which has a header which can be used to expand / collapse the body. I've got an example of it working on a page (inline) but now what to make it a reusable control that can be used as follows

```
<cc:CollapsiblePanel runat="server" Header="This is a collapsible panel">  
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="This is the contents of the panel" />  
</cc:CollapsiblePanel>
```

So, I want the CollapsiblePanel to render the header, the beginning of the container, then the contents of the container (i.e. the label in this case), and finally the end of container.

I'm unsure how to do this properly. I've seen some examples which override the rendering methods in order to insert controls at the right points, but it seems very hack-y.

What is the 'proper' way to do something like this? (.NET 4.0 if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the rendering methods is the best way to do this.  You would use RenderBeginTag and RenderEndTag.

Comment: The problem is, I'm using the CollapsiblePanelExtender from the Ajax Control Toolkit which will have some fairly complex rendering logic of it's own. It's not just a case of writing a couple of divs before and after, unfortunately. :)

Comment: In that case you probably don't even need to override the render methods.  Just create a composite control and you could add a panel and the extender in CreateChildControls and set the tagetID of the extender to the id of the panel.  asp.net should take care of the rest.